# Telegram BOT - How to get chat ID of users in my group?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I've been using a Telegram BOT to send notifications for a group, and for users.

I already know i can get Chat ID by receiving a message from the user on my bot, using getUpdates.

I also know i can get Group ID using the same method...

But what i really need is:
There is three users in my group.

1. My bot.
2. Me.
3. Another user that didn't sent any messages to my bot so it does not appear on getUpdates

Is it possible to get this third user his ID?
PS: I am the group owner, and also added my bot as Admin...

The third user is a normal user.
Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with the official Telegram Bot API.

Possible Workarounds:

Hold a list of your own. If a user is joining (new_chat_member), leaving (left_chat_member), somebody is sending a message in the group, and so on. Check [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) for more information.

Check if a user is a member of the group with [getChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmember).

Also may be helpful: [getChatMembersCount](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatmemberscount) and [getChatAdministrators](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getchatadministrators)

Comment: I couldnt figure it out how to do it. The only way is if the person sends a message to the bot, then i can get chat ID but without user sending the message it's was not possible for me...

Comment: If user joins the chat after bot (bot already has been in chat) it will receive new_chat_member message with user chat id. If user already has been in chat when bot joins and user does nothing - bot cannot get his chat id

Comment: I was able to discover user chat ID using new_chat_member indeed. Thank you.